# Corona SDK object follows "swipe" direction?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm trying to do something very simple as I'm new to Corona SDK, but I'm having a lot of issues with it.

What I'm trying to accomplish is when a user "swipes", "flings", "flicks" a certain area of the screen (an image set to half the screen) a ball in the middle of the screen moves in that direction at a set speed. No physics or anything special. So basically, if you swipe the image at an angle, the ball will move to that angle and eventually off the screen **unless** you "swipe" the ball again in a different direction.

What i have so far is:

```
physics.addBody( ball, "dynamic" )

function flick(event)
    if event.phase == "moved" then
        ball:applyForce( (ball.x) * 0.5, (ball.y) * 0.5, ball.x, ball.y )
    end
end
```

Currently when you move the ball it just shoots in one direction (the 0.5) how would i get the direction "flung"?

I'm new to corona and still trying to figure out the touch events. Still a little confusing to me.

Any help and advice is appreciated! Thanks everyone!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is missing the basic code sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to track where the touch starts and ends: this is the flick. The difference between start and end along x and y will give direction of motion of ball. If ball speed depends on how fast user flicked, you need to track time too. Also, I'm not sure why you are making the force proportional to the object's position: this means that if the object is at 0,0 there is no force, that's probably not what you want. You would just want a force proportional to the flick vector. The amount of time would determine the time. It would look something like this:

```
local flickStartTime = 0

local function touch(event)
    if event.phase == "began" then
        flickStartTime = system.timer()

    elseif event.phase == "ended" then
        local flickDuration = system.timer() - flickStartTime 
        if flickDuration <= 0 then return end -- ignore flick

        local speedX = (event.xStart - event.x)/flickDuration 
        local speedY = (event.yStart - event.y)/flickDuration 
        local coef = 0.1 -- adjust this via "trial and error" so moves at "reasonable" speed
        -- only react to flick if it was large enough
        if math.abs(event.xStart - event.x) > 10 or math.abs(event.yStart - event.y) > 10 then
            ball:applyForce( coef * speedX, coef * speedY, ball.x, ball.y )
        end
    end
end
```

However you said you don't want any physics, yet you apply force, do you mean you just want to set the velocity? Then instead of `applyForce` you would call `setLinearVelocity(speedX, speedY)`

```
local speedX = (event.xStart - event.x)/flickDuration 
local speedY = (event.yStart - event.y)/flickDuration 
local coef = 0.1 -- adjust this via "trial and error" so moves at "reasonable" speed
-- only react to flick if it was large enough
if math.abs(event.xStart - event.x) > 10 or math.abs(event.yStart - event.y) > 10 then
    ball:setLinearVelocity( coef * speedX, coef * speedY )
end
```

Comment: My answer was first and the code logic is almost the same, but got no points. Sucks to be me, i guess.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, `flick` is a touch listener. You must filter the event that is passed on, and determine which direction the user swiped. Read more about [touch listeners here](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/touch/index.html)

What you are interested in, is the `xStart` and `yStart` properties, and measure how much the user moved, something like this:

```
local function flick(event)
    if event.phase == "moved" then
        local diffX = event.xStart - event.x
        local diffY = event.yStart - event.y
        if math.abs(diffX) > 10 or math.abs(diffY) > 10 then
            ball:applyForce( (ball.x) * diffX, (ball.y) * diffY, ball.x, ball.y )
        end
    end
end
```